# The idea behind Stiffness switching method with NDsolve

Tags: numerical-integration, implementation-details, differential-equations

Does the Stiffness switching method with NDsolve switch just between multiple variants of 4th order Runge Kutta method or it uses also other methods?

Comment: The only way to overcome stiffness phenomenon is to switch to a suitable implicit scheme. Switching between explicit RK methods is pointless

Comment: Stiffness switching is [extensively documented in the Stiffness Detection tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html).

Comment: If you'd read [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching.html), you'd have been able to note that *Mathematica* uses a method appropriate for nonstiff systems by default, and switches to a stiff method every time [the built-in detector](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html) is tripped. Furthermore, by default, `"StiffnessSwitching"` uses a pair of Bulirsch-Stoer methods for the stiff and nonstiff methods. But really… **read the docs**! (And then maybe read Hairer/Nørsett/Wanner afterwards.)

Comment: @uranix, implicit schemes are stable instead of explicit methods. But is there another method? Can we get a.no-stiff equations to the same problem with change variables or other methods?